# Do different iOS 8 versions draw up UIButton differently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I've made an App and its deployment target is iOS 8.0 or above and for iPhones only.

I subclassed a button from XIB and implemented gradient onto it like this in initWithCoder:

```
  [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:51.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateSelected];

    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:140.0/255.0 green:140.0/255.0 blue:140.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2.5);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 3.5;
    [self normalGradient];
```

Normal Gradient:

```
- (void)normalGradient{
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [RBCGradientLayer normalBackground];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds;
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = self.layer.cornerRadius;
    [self.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

Now because there is one button that has a different width, gradientLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds doesn't work properly when I initialize it because of auto layout(or I might be wrong?). So I did a workaround in initWithCoder:

```
if (self.tag == 3){
self.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, 218, 36);
} else {
 self.layer.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

While this workout around is not clean, it gets the job done and works on all the simulators. However, when I test it on different devices, some will have the incorrect width (the width set in XIB) instead of the code I've implemented above.  I suspect this issue has to do with auto layout and as well as iOS versions.

Can anyone pinpoint why different versions of iOS(8 and above) might be drawing different UIs? OR provide a solution where I don't have to do the workaround when I subclass my button and initialize the button with the correct width *after auto layout has been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your gradient as following:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    //Update the frame of your layer too match your frame
}
```

This way the gradient will always be as big as your button.

Answer (score 0):

For layoutSubviews method you have to change gradientLayer bounds